# Авторские слова внутри прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оформить прямую речь в данном случае? Если бы это были только авторские слова внутри прямой речи, то я бы поняла, но там отрывок еще и заканчивается авторскими словами.

"П, - а. - П (несколько предложений)", - а.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы всё правильно написали:

П, — а. — П, — а.

Количество авторских вставок может быть любым, при необходимости. А их оформление от этого не меняется.

Единственное, на что нужно обратить внимание, так это: точку или запятую ставить после авторской речи (если она разрывает предложение в прямой речи, то нужно ставить запятую, если же вставляется после законченной фразы, то точку).

И ещё нюанс: иногда случает, что речь автора не поясняет прямую речь, а лишь сообщает информацию, косвенно касающуюся говорящего, диалога или происходящего. В таких случаях после прямой речи будет ставится точка, а авторская речь писаться с большой. В рамках одного абзаца допустимо комбинировать все эти приёмы, лишь бы это было оправданно с художественной точки зрения.